# Use calculated column to calculate another column in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to use a calculated column to calculate another column in Hive. There are many answers available to the same type of questions but those were for SQL not for Hive (HQL). Basically I want an alternative for the below command.

`select (colA + 1) as calCol1, (calCol1 + 2) as calCol2, (calCol2 + 1) as calCol3 from table;`

(Actual logic is lot more complex and recomputation is not preferred)

I cannot use nested queries here since I don't know how many columns will be calculated from how many columns. According to my understanding, I will need one subquery to use one calculated column, and so on.

Correct me if I am wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: _"I don't know how many columns will be calculated from how many columns"_ doesn't sound very encouraging. Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Maybe in some query I will use two calculated columns and in other I will be using four columns. That's why I need a general approach to do that.